# Apple Wallet pass never hits web service url

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, passbook, wallet

I can successfully create, add, and view passes on my iPod. However, through logging, I can confirm it never hits my server afterwards (to register the device, etc). Here is a sample of `pass.json`:

```
{
   "formatVersion":1,
   "passTypeIdentifier":"...",
   "teamIdentifier":"...",
   "authenticationToken":"...",
   "webServiceUrl":"https://.../wallet",
   ...
}
```

Notes:

- Does the `webServiceUrl` need to have slashes escaped? I have tried both with no success
- Will the `webServiceUrl` work with a self-signed certificate? This is currently residing on a dev server with no *real* SSL certificate

Comment: It should still attempt to register, however, it will be easier for you to use the 'http only' setting in the developer menu on your test device.  What sort of logging are you doing, server side only, or are you monitoring the console output of the iPod in Xcode? Have you turned on the additional logging function in your device's developer settings?

Comment: @PassKit I am only doing server-side logging. I will enable the HTTP only setting and check the device logs through Xcode and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: @PassKit I have enabled `additional logging`, `allow http services`, and `disable rate limiting` under the passkit developer settings on my device. When viewing the device logs in Xcode, nothing shows up when adding the pass to my wallet. Do you have any ideas where I should go next?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to use webServiceURL (not webServiceUrl), add an authenticationToken with 16+ characters, and use a URL with the https prefix.